# Math functions in JAVA and Delphi give different results

Tags: java, delphi, math, openstreetmap

I'm trying to convert an Open Street Maps latitude/longitude into a pixel position. I found this [example](https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/2687/coordinates-to-pixels-based-on-zoom) in java. When I convert the code to Delphi, the X result is correct, but the Y result is slightly out.

Java Code:

```
double lon = -89.08805;
double lat = 30.6393;
double zoom = 6; // 6.5156731549786215 would be possible too

double lon_rad = Math.toRadians(lon);
double lat_rad = Math.toRadians(lat);
double n = Math.pow(2.0, zoom);

double tileX = ((lon + 180) / 360) * n;
double tileY = (1 - (Math.log(Math.tan(lat_rad) + 1.0/Math.cos(lat_rad)) / Math.PI)) * n / 2.0;

System.out.println("tileX = "+tileX+" tileY = "+tileY);
```

Delphi Code:

```
function LatLngToTilePixels(Lat, Lng: Double; ZoomLevel: Integer): TPointF;
var
  lon_rad, lat_rad, n: Double;
  TileX, TileY: Double;
begin
  lon_rad := DegToRad(Lng);
  lat_rad := DegToRad(Lat);

  n := Power(2.0, ZoomLevel);

  Result.X := ((Lng + 180) / 360) * n;
  Result.Y := (1 - (Math.Log10(Math.tan(lat_rad) + 1.0/cos(lat_rad)) / PI)) * n / 2.0;
end;
```

The results, using the inputs given in the example (lat=30.6393, lng=-89.08805, zoom=6) are:

JAVA:

tileX = 16.162124444444444

tileY = 26.273150713795616

Delphi:

tileX=16.1621244444444

tileY = 29.5128609563099 <--- wrong result

I have a feeling that the problem may be the math.log call. JAVA uses log, but Delphi uses log10. I have tried log2, but the result is even worse.

Comment: Try the Java code with [strictfp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strictfp).

Comment: Try `ln` instead of `Math.Log10`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You use logarithms of different bases:

**Java:** base `e`, i.e. the natural logarithm, see [Math.log(double)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#log-double-)

**Delphi:** Obviously base 10

You can use the following formula to calculate the logarithm to a base that is not supported:

`log_a(b) = log_x(b) / log_x(a)`

AFAIK there is a `Ln` function in delphi, that calculates the natural logarithm, at least it's listed [here](http://www.efg2.com/Lab/Library/Delphi/MathFunctions/General.htm#Logarithm).

Comment: ln(x) works perfectly. Should have listened in math :)

Comment: Unbelievable that in Java the logarithm on base `e` is called "log". So what is the logarithm in Java on base 10 called?

Comment: @iamjoosy: [log10](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#log10-double-)

Comment: This is actually fairly common.  What is called `ln` on a calculator is frequently "log" in a standard math library. Java and the standard C library are the same here, which makes sense since Java inherits many syntactical elements and ideas from C and C++

Comment: @WarrenP It's also "log" in Python, although you can supply an optional second parameter to use a base other than e.

Comment: FWIW: when we still used logarithm tables in school, these were base 10, not base `e`. I always learned that `ln` is base `e` and `log` is base 10.

Comment: Pure mathematicians would always use log to mean natural logarithm. For me at least, it always grates that I have to write `Ln` for the natural logarithm in Delphi.